# Relational database design when dealing with m2m field

Tags: sql, database-design

Let's say I have the following tables :

`User : id, login, password`

`Card : id, name, value`

And an `User` can have the same `Card` multiple times. Eg : the `User` with the id 1 can have multiple `Card` with the id 1.

I would create the following table :

`UserCard : id, user_id, card_id`

So for the example, `UserCard` could looks like :

```
| id | user_id | card_id |
|1   | 1       | 1       |
|2   | 1       | 1       |
|3   | 1       | 2       |
```

However a colleague with whom I discussed about this told me that having some lines with the same values is bad design and

```
| id | user_id | card_id | quantity |
|1   | 1       | 1       | 2        |
|2   | 1       | 2       | 1        |
```

would be the best way to do it because it removes duplicates lines.

To my point of view this is wrong for the following reasons :

- `quantity` can be calculated, therefore the field is useless
- Adding the `quantity` field add a lot of unnecessary stuff, like before adding a card to an user I have to check if the user already own this card (if he does, I increment the quantity field, otherwise I add the card)
- I should let the DBMS deal with this kind of stuff

My colleague point of view was :

- Having duplicates lines in a table used only for relationship for two other tables is dirty
- Well can't remember other point he made, but to him what I proposed was very unoptimised.

---

The question :

What would be the best database design for this case ?
An user can have 0 or any cards with the same ID

EDIT :

we're using Django with postgrsql
There is no colleague, I was just wondering what would be the best database design

Comment: What does it mean when a user has the same card multiple times?

Comment: The exemple is unclear ? I am not sure on how to rephrase it since english is not my mother tongue

Comment: Many times such a many-to-many table would use the two FK columns as its PK, though in your design that's not possible.  Which begs the question... Why do the same two entities have multiple relationships in this domain?  What is the purpose of it?  Is there more information to a "relationship" in this case than simply the connection itself?  For example, consider a rental car system in which the same person may have rented the same car twice.  There would be two relationships, but the relationship itself has considerably more information, enough to make it its own domain entity.

Comment: I don't understand your comment @David, `user_id` and `card_id` are both foreign key referencing primary key respectively from `User` and `Card` tables

Comment: @L.Faros: But are they part of the PK on the `UserCard` table?  They can't be the sole PK on that table because records therein are repeated.  It looks as though that table has its own `id` column which is likely the sole PK.  But what I'm getting at in my example, and what Gordon asked directly above, is *why* there needs to be support for repeated relationship records.  What does it *mean* when this happens in the domain?  You and your colleague can debate best practices all you want, but unless you're actually building something that has semantic meaning then it's pointless.

Comment: I don't think this is a m2m situation, because the use table has one record per user. So it's one-to-many.

In this situation I'd add qty since you that will leave you fewer entries in the primary key index for faster processing.

But in the real world you would likely have more data on each entry on the Card table (issue date, etc) so be forced into the first example you outline.

Comment: @L.Faros: Your question is essentially opinion-based at this point.  Both designs accomplish the same thing.  Without any understanding of what is actually being modeled in this domain, you and your colleague are simply exchanging opinions.  There is no "one best solution" which fits all possible problems.

Comment: @L.Faros . . . I understand the *fact* of a user having the same card multiple times.  I don't understand the *meaning*.  For instance, I have only one credit card from a given bank at any time.  There is no such thing as a duplicate.

Comment: @David, Yeah I tried to narrow down my question in my last edit, sadly it didn't work. Whatever, the question stays quite simple : it's only about adding a counter or not

Comment: @GordonLinoff well i should have been clearer, that one is on me. By card I just meant some cards like in a game (like hearthstone or magic). Not some kind of payment stuff

Comment: @L.Faros: That still brings the same question... How can the same person be holding the same card twice?  It sounds like the data model isn't accurately representing the domain.  In a card game, I can hold two cards which have all of the same attributes.  But I can't hold the same physical card twice.  The `Card` table isn't accurately representing the objects it models.  Both designs are wrong, as both imply that a single instance of an object can exist multiple times.  (Two identical twins are not the same person.)

Comment: @David let's say there is a card named Dog, you can have two "dog" card in your hand right ? One will have the ID 1 and one the ID 13. But you want to know what the stats are onn the card with ID 1 or 13

Comment: @L.Faros: Both of those `Card` records can have the same stats, or can have a FK to a single `CardCatalog` record which contains the stats shared by those two cards.  But the point is that if you model the data to have two cards instead of trying to make the data think there's only one card, the question becomes moot.  Model the domain accurately and you won't have to debate otherwise arbitrary design decisions.

Comment: Duplicate rows are bad. Duplicate subrows are not bad per se. Time to read a textbook on information modeling, the relational model & database design. (Nb--A manual for a design tool, api or language to record designs is not a manual/tutorial on design.) PS If you cannot state a claim "precisely* then you are not asking a question & you are expecting us to guess what was meant. If you can't reproduce the *argument* for a claim then you are just asking us to reproduce a textbook on the topic with a bespoke example & you are expecting to guess which claim was meant.

Answer (score 1):

Your colleague is right.  I'll give you a gloss on the theory and an example of why, but you'd be better served by reading CJ Date's textbook.

The basic problem with your UserCard table is that it has no *natural key*.  You stuck a meaningless `id` on it to make it "unique", but there's no *meaningful* distinction between id 1 and id 2:  There's no differences in their values, therefore the things they represent are indistinguishable.  When you find yourself tracking things you can't tell apart, the usual solution is to count them.  That's what you bank does with dollars.

Relational theory is based on sets of distinct (nonrepeating) elements.   You ignore that foundation at your peril.

As a practical matter -- and only one example -- what happens when the user drops one card?  How will you delete the indistinguishable row?  Your colleague might say

```
update UserCard set quantity = quantity - 1 where user = 1 and card = 1
delete UserCard where quantity = 0
```

What will you do?  Work around the problem with another nontheoretical kludge like `limit 1`?  What if the limit isn't 1, because an arbitrary group of users dropped their cards?

You partly helped yourself out with your artificial uniqueness:

```
delete UserCard where id = 
       (select min(id) from UserCard where user = 1 and card = 1)
```

which illustrates how uniqueness is helpful.  But `quantity` is your friend.  Your design, and query, consequently, are both simpler if you use the theory instead of fighting it.

Comment: If there is an id then there is no need for a count & if there is a count then there is no need for an id. I'd agree that if there is no business rule that uses a surrogate as an identifier then a count is less clumsy. However your argument is not clear. You say "There's no differences in their value"--but they clearly are different values. You *mean* no difference in--what? Then you say, "therefore the things they represent are indistinguishable"--again, the things may or may not be indistinguishabile but the problem is that we cannot distinguish things *via that surrogate*.

Comment: @philipxy, I assume `id` was added and is not a natural part of the data.  If you drop `id` -- which afaict tell was added robotically, because no reason is given for it -- then you're left with an indistinguishable row, for which (as you know) quantity is the obvious answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this can help:

```
create table #user
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    login nvarchar(100),
    password nvarchar(100)
)
create table #card
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    name nvarchar(100),
    value int
)
create table #usercard
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    user_id int, /* <-- (in theory) foreign key to #user table*/
    card_id int /* <-- (in theory) foreign key to #card table */
)
insert into #user (login, password) values
('user1','password1'),
('user2','password2')

insert into #card (name, value) values
('card1', 1),
('card2', 2),
('card3', 3)

insert into #usercard (user_id, card_id) values
(1,1),
(1,2),
(2,3)

select a.id as user_id, count(b.card_id) as quantity from #user a
inner join #usercard b on a.id = b.user_id
inner join #card c on b.card_id = c.id
group by a.id
```

In database design, the 3rd table (#usercard) is called "Junction Table". And this design is preferred when you wanted to attain database normalization.

Comment: How exactly does this answer the question being asked?  The OP has already created the exact structure you're demonstrating.

Comment: Because his colleague was worried about having a bad design when they will have to update the quantity manually. Well not exactly true since they can achieve what they want (and not having a bad design) by having to count the "quantity" based from the junction table.

Comment: *"his colleague was worried about having a bad design when they will have to update the quantity manually"* - You got that backwards.  The OP is recommending the approach you describe in this answer, his colleague is recommending a single relationship record with a `quantity` field.  Though honestly, looking at the question... Where does the OP even *ask* a question?  Thus, what question is this answering?

Comment: Ah! sorry. I missed the possible example table given by his colleague. I would agree with your comments above but I am unable to reply to that thread.

Comment: @L.Faros. If your question is _"Whatever, the question stays quite simple : it's only about adding a counter or not "_..., my answer would be: "don't". You have to calculate that counter.

Comment: That's quite on spot, question was about adding a counter or not if you adapt your answer i'd gladly accept it

Comment: Anytime @L.Faros :)